# How can I make an offset line in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke

I'm really new to Photoshop and I couldn't really make sense of the answers of similar questions. So if someone could give me a step by step for my problem, that'd be amazing.

[image]

I'm trying to make an offset line based on those portrait contours and then fill the space in between. Hopefully the imgur makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A friendly redditor helped me out with the question. 
The answer that worked is as follows:

---

ChicoSuaveIII 12 minutes ago  - https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/dr71c5/how_do_i_make_an_offset_line_and_then_fill_the/?

Why don't you try this:

1 First, rasterize the image.

2 Use the "Wand Tool" to select the blank area around the two figures.

3 Next, use the "Expand" and "Contract" options under the Select/Modify menu to adjust the distance you want from the figures.

4 Once you have the right distance you want, under the Select/Modify menu again, choose the "Border" option and choose a thin border, maybe three or four pixels.

5 Use the Fill Tool to fill in the border with whatever color you like.

I just tried out the above myself. It does work.

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshots your layers are already raster (bitmap). So:

1. duplicate your layer (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>)
2. Double-click on the newly created layer thumbnail (in the Layers panel) and add a Stroke.
3. Change the stroke thickness to be whatever size you want the **gap** to be.
4. Right-click the layer's name in the Layers panel and select **Rasterize Layer Style**
5. Change the **Fill** (on top of the Layers panel) to **0%**. The layer will become invisible.  [image]
6. Add a new **Stroke** to this layer and adjust the thickness to whatever value you want.

Whenever you need a larger gap, just repeat steps 3-4-6 on the stroke layer until you get the correct gap size. If you need a smaller gap just duplicate your original layer again and repeat 1-6.